# How to revert back commit from different branch which affected branch not intended to be affected?

Tags: git

I was working on a branch `hello-feature`

I then switched to a different branch `hello-feature-copy`

I intended to push changes for `hello-feature-copy` so that my colleague could see them, and not affect my local development in `hello-feature`.

Now it seems that all changes in `hello-feature` are gone. How to revert this?

This is the command history I got after running `history`

```
 1116  git status
 1117  git add src
 1118* git checkout -b hello-feature-copy
 1119* git checkout -
 1120  git checkout -b hello-feature-copy
 1121  git checkout -
 1122  git status
 1123  git checkout -
 1124  git add .
 1125  git commit -m “work for you to see”
```

Comment: What does `git checkout -` mean? What did Git say when you said _that_?

Comment: @AD7six there were stuff on `hello-feature` I didn't commit. I changed to the new branch and then did the commit. @matt that will bring you back to the previous branch you were on. When I change back it says `branch ahead of origin/hello-feature` by 1 commit

Comment: @matt it means check out the previous commitish, so the first one (for example) is the same as `git checkout hello-feature`

Comment: @AD7six Thanks, that one had me confused. I knew about `@{-1}` but not simple hyphen. — Okay, I see this documented under `git switch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you did just from the `history` (though it was nice of you to provide it), but this seems fairly straightforward, normal behavior. I think the key piece of info you're missing is that when you `checkout` a branch, Git throws your whole working tree away (the files you can see) and replaces it with a copy of the files in the most recent commit on that branch (which technically *is* the branch).

Let's say I'm on `main` and I say this:

```
% echo hello > hello.txt
% git add .
% git checkout -b mybranch
% git commit -m'here you go'
% git switch main
```

Now where's *hello.txt*? I don't see it. Well, of course not! I'm back on `main`. The commit where I added that file is on `mybranch`, not on `main`. When I switched back to `main`, the set of visible files (the working tree) was replaced with the files in the most recent commit on `main`. And *hello.txt* is not one of those.

Comment: OP, it may seem like I haven't actually answered the question; that's true, because I don't understand what the question is. The phrase "How to revert this?" doesn't communicate anything to me. So instead I've tried to show you how to reason about what you're doing, so that you can understand what's happening.